# Jquery and ajax How to parse json?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm using Jquery and ajax.

I have a simple **form** and my **jquery** :

This is a piece of the code :

```
username = $('input[name="username"]').val(); 
$.post("api.php", {username: username}, function(data) {  
    if(data == "error") {
        data("erreur");
    } else {
        alert(data);
        $('input[name="subscribers"]').attr("placeholder", "something").blur();
        $('input[name="viewCount"]').attr("placeholder", "something").blur();
    }
});
```

And the result of `alert(data);`

```
{"total":"628729","abo":"1646"}
```

I would like to put the result of **total** and the result of **abo** into my placeolder :

```
$('input[name="subscribers"]').attr("placeholder", ?abo?).blur();
```

But i don't know who to recover the result of the json and take the value of **total** and **abo**

*note : my json is genrate by the file api.php with `json_encode`*

Comment: Try to add a 4th parameter to the `$.post` call: `$.post('api.php', {username: username}, function(data){}, 'json'), to tell jQuery to parse the JSON.  Then `data` will be an object (not a function).  Then you can access `data.total` and `data.abo`.

Comment: have a look at: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

Comment: Also, in case of an error, *don't* reply with `"error"`.  Reply with `{error:true}`, so that you can have jQuery parse it as JSON and check for `data.error`

Comment: @RocketHazmat if i use your solution with the parameter , 'json' it's works fine, but i can also use "JSON.parse(data); ", which one is better ?

Comment: @Martialp: I prefer not to have to manually call `JSON.parse`, but it's up to you.

Comment: well, i use "$.post('api.php', {username: username}, function(data){}, 'json')", i think it's better like this :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery appears to be trying to handle your JSON as text (or, more likely, HTML).

Tell jQuery that it is JSON:

```
<?php header("Content-Type: application/json"); ?>
```

Then you can just:

```
foo = data.total
```

Comment: If there is an error, it should be handled with an HTTP status code and an `error` handler as well as a `success` handler. (But it doesn't stop that, you can do `Content-Type: text/plain` if you want to send back a plain text message body and then the comparison will work).

Comment: it's something that he is echo in response,else case he response the json data

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    $('input[name="subscribers"]').attr("placeholder", data.abo).blur();
}
```

Comment: @RocketHazmat You are right. If you can change your server side code, then you should handle it at server side and use data as it is. Agreed!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$.parseJSON()` to parse json

```
username = $('input[name="username"]').val(); 
$.post("api.php", {username: username}, function(data) {  
    if(data == "error") {
        data("erreur");
    } else {
        alert(data);
        data=$.parseJSON(data); // add this line
        $('input[name="subscribers"]').attr("placeholder", "something").blur();
        $('input[name="viewCount"]').attr("placeholder", "something").blur();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON is a string representing (in this case) an object, so `data` is a string. In order to go from the string to the object you need to *parse* it. There's a `JSON.parse()` function to do that:

```
if(data == "error") {
    data("erreur");
} else {
    alert(data);
    var yourObj = JSON.parse(data);
    $('input[name="subscribers"]').attr("placeholder", yourObj.abo).blur();
    $('input[name="viewCount"]').attr("placeholder", yourObj.subscribers).blur();
}
```

Comment: Why use `JSON.parse`, when you can tell jQuery to do it for you by setting `Content-Type: application/json` or passing `'json'` as a 4th parameter to `$.post`?

Comment: @RocketHazmat Mostly because I'm lazy and the implicit parsing from jQuery would break the `if(data == "error")` test. You're correct, though, a better solution would be to have jQuery implicitly parse it and return a property in the object that indicates whether there was an error.

Comment: I guess, though I'd suggest on an error responding with `{error:true}` so you could check for `data.error`.